# How to prove that a polynomial algorithm runtime is O(n)?

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, asymptotics, computer-science

The definition of "Big-Oh" is that the runtime $T(N) = O(f(N))$ if there are positive constants c and $n_0$ such that $T(N) \leq cf(N)$ for all $N \geq n_0$. With this in mind, I am trying to understand the proof for how $3n^2 + 4n - 2 = O(n^2).$

I do not understand steps two and three. Why does step 2 set $n_0 = 1,$ and why does step 3 set $c = 6?$

> Find $c$ and $n_0$ such that $3n^2 + 4n -2 \leq cn^2$ for all $n \geq n_0.$

1. Divide both sides by $n^2$ to get $3 + 4/n - 2/n^2\leq n_0$
2. If we choose $n_0$ equal to 1, we need value of $c$ such that: $3 + 4 -2 \leq c.$
3. We can set $c = 6,$ so we have: $3n^2 + 4n -2 \leq6n^2$ for all $n \geq 1.$

Thus, $3n^2 + 4n - 2 = O(n^2).$

Comment: That step is not a logical step - that is, we know that when. $n=1,$ we need $c\geq 5,$ but the case $n=1$ is certainly not sufficient for all $n.$ Rather, it is just a "so let's try $6!$" step.  (It turns out, $3+4/n-2/n^2\leq 5$ for all $n\geq 1,$ but that isn't obviously true just from the case $n=1.$)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Divide both sides by $n^2$ to get 3 + 4/n - 2/$n^2$ $\leq$ $n_0$
> 2. If we choose $n_0$ equal to 1, we need value of c such that: 3 + 4 -2 $\leq$ c

- $f(x) = 4/x - 2/x^2 $ is decreasing for $x \ge 1$, so $3+4/n-2/n^2 =3+f(n)$ $\le 3+f(1)$ $=3+4-2$ for $n \ge 1$, which justifies the choice $n_0=1$.

> 3. We can set c = 6, so we have: 3n$^2$ + 4n -2 $\leq$ 6$n^2$ for all n $\geq$ 1.

- $3+4-2 = 5 \le 6$, which justifies the choice $c=6$ (though $c=5$ would have worked, too).

Note that the choices are not unique. Could have, for example, just as well chosen $c=5$ and $n_0=0$, since $3n^2 + 4n -2 \leq c n^2 \iff (c-3)n^2 - 4n + 2 \ge 0$, and a sufficient condition is $\frac{1}{4}\Delta = 4 - 2(c-3) \le 0 \iff 2c \ge 10$.